# What is the difference between Primary key and prime attribute?

Tags: rdbms, database

Is there any difference between primary key (which is a composite key) and a prime attribute?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**A candidate key** is a key that uniquely identifies rows in a table. Any of the identified candidate keys can be used as the table's primary key. 
Candidate keys that are not part of the primary key are called **alternate keys**. One can describe a candidate key as **a super key** that contains only the minimum number of columns necessary to determine uniqueness.

**Prime attributes** are the attributes of the candidate key which defines the uniqueness (Eg: SSN number in an employee database)

**A primary key** is a column in a table whose values uniquely identify the rows in the table. The primary key is chosen from this list of candidates based on its perceived value to the business as an identifier.

A primary key value:

- Must uniquely identify the row;
- cannot have NULL values;
- Should not change over the time;
- and Should be as short as possible.

If the primary key is a combination of more than one column then it is called as **composite key**.

Comment: Thanks. That means if (name, address) is a primary key then "name" and "address" are its prime attributes ?

Comment: It means what makes it unique. in your case it is name and address

Comment: So if AB and AC, both are candidate keys in a relation ABC and AB is chosen as primary key, then A,B and C will be prime attribute?

Comment: @thepurpleowl yes, A, B, C are prime attributes because they are a part of candidate key.

Answer (score 6):

In order to understand the difference primary key and prime attributes, one should first know what is a super and candidate key.

**Super Key:** Any attribute/combination of attributes whose closure, on
the basis of given functional dependencies, determines the
complete relation is a **Super Key**. *(A relation could have more than one super keys)*

For example in relation 
**R(A,B,C,D)**;
given the functional dependencies as:

ABC->D

AB->CD

A->BCD

D->ABC

Following are the super keys

ABC; because its closure gives the complete relation i.e., (ABC)->ABCD

AB; because it's closer also gives the complete relation i.e., (AB)->ABCD

A; because it's closure also gives the complete relation i.e., (A)->ABCD

D; because it's closure also gives the complete relation i.e., (D)->ABCD

**Candidate Key:** Any super key whose proper subset is not a super key is a
**Candidate Key.** *(A relation could have more than one candidate keys)*

So, in the example above, **A** and **D** are the only candidate keys.

**Primary Key:** Any candidate key (may or may not be minimal) which is being chosen by the database designer to identify record is a Primary Key. *(A relation can have only one primary key/*(composite primary key: primary key that is made up of more than one columns)*)*

In the example above, **A** *(let's say)* is the primary key.

**Prime Attributes:** An attribute that is present in any of the candidate keys is a prime attribute.

So, in the example above, **A** and **D** are prime attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Primary keys may consist of a single attribute or multiple attributes in combination.
For example

```
name login email
Bob  catlover catlover@123.com
Jason doglover doglover@123.com
```

The login would be the primary key and the attribute will be the catlover/doglover everything that is attributed in that key

Comment: "attribute will be the catlover/doglover". What does that mean? That is data or attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Student_table {IndexNo,Name,ExamNo,Age,Class,City}

- {IndexNo},{Name,ExamNo} are the candidates keys. From them I'ill choose {IndexNo} as the Primary Key.Those all indexNo,Name,ExamNo are prime attributes

Employee_table {ID,Name,MobileNo,Age,Height}

- {ID},{MobileNo} are the candidates keys. From them I'ill choose {ID} as the Primary Key.Those all ID,MobileNo attributes are prime attributes

Lets Look at the definitions. (Attributes mean columns)

**Candidate key** - Attributes or combination of attributes that can used to uniquely identify table records.

**Prime key** - Attribute that forms candidate keys.

**Primary Key** - A attribute from candidate keys, Than used to Uniquely identify the 
 table records.It should Unique, Not Null, Should not update frequently.

Comment: in your ex: Student_table {IndexNo,Name,ExamNo,Age,Class,City} why not choose (name, examno, age) ? why only 2 attributes (name, examno) ?

Comment: actually I'm still very confused how to determine the candidate key, or in Employee_table(ID,Name,MobileNo,Age,Height) why you not choose {ID}, {MobileNo}, {Name,Age} ?

Comment: @Yuresh Karunanayake, can you please provide link to a reference

Answer (score 0):

**Primary key:** A primary key is a column (or combination of columns) designated to uniquely identify all records in the table.

**Prime Attributes:** Ideally all attributes with no incoming edge form set of prime
attribute(s).